# Internal Speaker Beep in Windows 8 Embedded Standard

Tags: c#, beep, windows-embedded-8

I've got an industrial panel which running a 32-bit version of Windows Embedded 8 Standard. It is required to use the internal speaker to make beep sounds. Connecting external speakers is not an option.

Previously this was running XP based Windows Embedded Standard and using Console.Beep in C# will use the internal speaker. However in Windows 8 Embedded Standard this seems to use the external speakers instead, despite not being connected up.

The internal speaker is still operational - the touchscreen driver (eGalaxTouch) still uses the internal speaker when tapping the screen, however I cannot replicate this in my own application.

I've tried the following from a C# application with no effect;

```
Console.Beep()
MessageBeep() (user32.dll)
Beep() (kernel32.dll)
SystemSounds.Beep.Play()
```

I understand this is not possible from Windows 7 64-bit onwards, but I'm using 32-bit OS here and it still works with the touchscreen?

While a solution in C#/.NET would be ideal, I'd be up for other solutions (C/C++/whatever).

Comment: This sounds like its down to the windows setup  not the c# code

Comment: In the Registry is an entry for HKCU\Control Panel\Sound\Beep, which can allegedly disable the beep by setting to 'no' but this is already set to 'yes'.

Answer (score 0):

Typically shortly after posting the question, I find an answer...

Basically, using the 'Beep.sys' file from the Windows (XP) Embedded Standard in place of the Windows 8 Embedded version allows Console.Beep to work as expected.

harrymc's answer to a similar question https://superuser.com/a/230167/83606 below. Note that there is no 'Beep' device in the device manager in Windows 8 (Embedded), but the procedure is otherwise similar.

From [Default Beep PC Speaker changed in windows 7 – How to get back to old style](http://www.windowsreference.com/windows-7/default-beep-pc-speaker-changed-in-windows-7-how-to-get-back-to-old-style/) :

> The default beep is controlled by a
>   driver under,
>   `c:\windows\system32\drivers\beep.sys`.
>   Maybe if you switched it out with a
>   driver from XP/Vista it would increase
>   the volume.
>
> To see this driver you have to open
>   device manager then click on View >
>   Show hidden devices.  Then under
>   Non-Plug and Play Drivers you’ll see
>   “Beep.”  This is the driver that runs
>   your beep. Right click on it then
>   choose properties and go to the driver
>   tab, then click on Driver Details… 
>   This shows the file version which
>   looks like it’s been change with
>   Windows 7.  So replace it with an
>   older version and see what happens.
>
> Procedure to follow :
>
> 1. Boot from an UBCD4WIN disc (or BartPE if you don’t have an SATA hard
>      drive)
> 2. Take ownership of the “C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\Beep.sys”
>      file and give the local
>      “Administrators” Group “Full Control”
>      permissions.
> 3. Rename “Beep.sys” to “Beep.old” (just in case)
> 4. Copy “Beep.sys” from an XP machine to this location.