# Internal speaker under Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows-10, speaker

since Windows 7 the "Beep" function from Windows API has been changed to make the sound come from the default audio device instead of the internal audio speaker; but the speaker output in motherboards that still have it should still be usable by past standards.

Is there any way to access the motherboard directly with a C++ program running on a Windows 10 machine and "send" a low level signal to trigger the internal speaker?

I don't know anything about that kind of low level interactions so i'd like to have some "how does it work" after the "how to do it" response, if there's a way to do it.

Also if it's possible, with the program crash in a machine that doesn't have an internal speaker, will it have undefined side effects or will it just be ignored?

---

Before i get a duplicate question flag from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42576225/internal-speaker-beep-in-windows-8-embedded-standard), i'm not asking for a workaround that involves replacing windows files.

Comment: You're assuming computers these days actually have a "blooper", the old PC speaker subsystem. Most don't. Some servers might, as a legacy support feature, but notebooks won't.

Comment: i'm not assuming, read the entire question @tadman "Also if it's possible, with the program crash in a machine that doesn't have an internal speaker, will it have undefined side effects or will it just be ignored?"
I'm assuming the speaker output uses a standard motherboard signal and i don't know if its kept reserved and unused or if its recycled for other things in motherboards that don't have it.

Comment: Windows doesn't really let you access the low-level hardware, so unless you can find a Windows function that maps directly to the old booper hardware, the answer's probably "no".

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216931/play-sound-on-internal-speakers-and-possibility-to-use-old-xp-api-function and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29714604/make-beep-sound-in-bios